# Why do my laser rays flicker?

Tags: javascript, animation

I'm trying my hands at some simple game programming in Javascript and have come to realize I need to change the way I handle sprites. The only question is, "how"?

I have a hero that moves around with the arrow keys and fires laser rays with WASD. This is how I define rays:

```
function Ray (x, y, width, height, direction, index) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.direction = direction;
    this.index = index;
    this.speed = 512;
    this.disabled = false;
}
```

The index just indicates where in an array of rays (heh) it is being stored. I currently have a hard-coded limit of 5 simultaneous rays, although the other restrictions (screen size, ray size, speed, hero size etc) shouldn't allow for more than 4:

```
var rays = [];
var numberOfRays = 0;
var rayLimit = 5;
var shotClock = 300;
```

And so, in the update() function that gets called by the game loop, I have listeners for the WASD keys. They look like this:

```
// D
    if (68 in keysDown && numberOfRays <= rayLimit && Date.now() - lastShootTime > shotClock) {
        lastShootTime = Date.now();
        var newRayIndex = findFreeRay();        
        rays[newRayIndex] = new Ray(hero.x + hero.width + 12, hero.y + hero.height / 2, rayImage.width, rayImage.height, 'right', newRayIndex);         
        numberOfRays++;                 
    }
```

(findFreeRay() just returns the lowest unused or disabled (off the screen) index in rays[])

Earlier in the update() method (I have also tried putting it later) I have the logic for updating ray movement:

```
rays.forEach(function(ray) {
        if (ray != null && !ray.disabled) {
            switch(ray.direction) {
                case 'right':
                    ray.x += ray.speed * modifier;                  
                    break;
                case 'left':
                    ray.x -= ray.speed * modifier;
                    break;
                case 'up':
                    ray.y -= ray.speed * modifier;
                    break;
                case 'down':
                    ray.y += ray.speed * modifier;
                    break;
            }
        }       
    });
```

Finally, there is the image for the ray (actually, one for horizontal rays and another one for vertical rays). Currently, I am using one Image object of each globally, that the existing rays share. But I have also tried, without much luck, to create individual image objects for every ray.

```
// Ray images
var rayReady = false;
var rayImage = new Image();
rayImage.onload = function() {
    rayReady = true;
};
rayImage.src = "images/ray.png";

var rayVertReady = false;
var rayVertImage = new Image();
rayVertImage.onload = function() {
    rayVertReady = true;
};
rayVertImage.src = "images/ray_vert.png";
```

And here is how they get drawn:

```
if (rayReady && rayVertReady && numberOfRays > 0) {
        rays.forEach(function(ray) {            
            if (ray.x > canvas.width
                    || ray.x + ray.width < 0
                    || ray.y > canvas.height
                    || ray.y + ray.height < 0) {                        
                        numberOfRays--;                 
                        ray.disabled = true;                    
                }
            else if (ray.direction == 'right' || ray.direction == 'left'){
                ctx.drawImage(rayImage, ray.x, ray.y);          
            }
            else {
                ctx.drawImage(rayVertImage, ray.x, ray.y);
            }               
        });     
    }
```

**The problem**
After shooting only a few rays, new ones start to either flicker and disappear, or stay invisible altogether. They actually exist as gameplay objects though, as they can hit targets.

What likely causes this flickering?

(credit to Matt Hackett for the base of this code)

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Vr3MW/

Comment: just saying : it would be so easier to help you with a "playable" [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: gotcha, I'll try to set something up.

Comment: Okay, I have a fiddle up at http://jsfiddle.net/Vr3MW/ now. With imagery linked from elsewhere on the web, of course.

Comment: I'm no expert, but I'd recommend doing a Google search for [requestAnimationFrame](http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/). It will probably help. Also, try to use the new keyword a little as possible (reuse objects instead of creating them over and over).

Comment: Oh yeah, reusage sounds like a good idea. I'll get right to that. Will look further into requestAnimationFrame too. Thanks!